# Вопрос по гугл ридеру

Tags: php

Друзья как можно из гугл ридера http://www.google.com/reader/  импортировать к себе все рссины ? желательн ов файл или получить линк

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто. Заходим в настройки аккаунта (шестеренка справа вверху), выбираем настройки Reader'a. Там переходим на вкладку "импорт-экспорт" и жмем кнопку "Загрузить". Получим opml файл. Он содержит список всех подписок в виде xml. Как это сделать на php - это уже самостоятельно.

Но если хочется сделать синхронизацию с ридером (то есть, свой ридер к примеру), то нужно пользоваться api google reader'a, для которого народ написал и обвязку для [php](https://github.com/dimmduh/Google-Reader-API-PHP-class). Там найдете ссылки на другие обвязки и упоминания того, что вроде официального апи нет.